# Word for the combination of location and orientation (other than transform)

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to come up with a name for a class that encompasses an entity's position and orientation. This class isn't a transformation in the 3D sense- a transformation is something this class might create in order to tell the 3D where to draw. This class is meant to describe where an entity is.

I just know there's a good word for this!

Comment: "Spatial". I usually have it as a component of every entity. I believe I picked this up from GIS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about PositionState?  Could also include other state parameters of the position like bounding box issues.

Comment: Not bad! Probably better to be straightforward like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas from a thesaurus: abode, locus, place, placing, placement, position, post, seat, setting, site, spot, station

Comment: I kind of like "Placement"! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about 'CurrentState'? or 'CurrentTransformationalState'? Or  just 'TransformState'?